# Set focus on the second table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to focus on the second table in the same way I did with the first table but I couldn't set focus on the second table.

```js
(function ($) {
  $.fn.formNavigation = function () {
    $(this).each(function () {

      $(this).find('input').on('keydown', function(e) {

        if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
          if ($(this).closest('td').next().find('input').length>0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').focus();
          } else if ($(this).closest('tr').next().children().eq(1).find('input').length>0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('tr').next().children().eq(0).find('input').focus();

          } else if ($(this).siblings('table')) {
            //$(this).closest('table').find('tr').children().eq($(this).closest('td').index()).find('input').focus();
          }
        } 
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.gridexample').formNavigation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="gridexample">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="gridexample">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to set focus on the second table? ->tr->td

Comment: Do you want to set the focus in second table's first text box?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Okay, do you want to do that on page load or any specific event?

Comment: You could select the table directly if you gave it its own id or class. For example, `let table2 = document.getElementById("table2");` (and in your HTML, `<table id="table2" class="gridexample">`). Once you have the desired table element identified in the script, your same jQuery code should find the input correctly (since the structure of the two tables is identical.)

Comment: @Prashant Zombade  it doesn't matter. i just need solution whatever your way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Manipulate the [jQuery Collection](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

It looks like you want the <kbd>enter</kbd>/<kbd>return</kbd> key to act like a <kbd>tab</kbd> key? If so then, then target the tags as a jQuery Collection (i.e. `$('input')`) and just bind to the top ancestor tag -- an ancestor that is shared by all tags within the collection (i.e. `$('table')`). The extension has been modified so that you can pass in any selector for ancestor and collection parameters, so now you can target anything rather than just `input`.

**Demo 1** is the setup required in OP question -- `input` in a `table`.

**Demo 2** is setup with a mixed collection -- `textarea` and `select` in a `form`.

### Demo 1

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.enterNav = function(collection) {
    $(collection).on('keydown', function(e) {
      var idx = $(this).index(collection);
      if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        $(collection).eq(idx + 1).focus();
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

// $(ancestor).enterNav(collection)

$('table').enterNav('input');
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Demo 2

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.enterNav = function(collection) {
    $(collection).on('keydown', function(e) {
      var idx = $(this).index(collection);
      if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        $(collection).eq(idx + 1).focus();
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

// $(ancestor).enterNav(collection)

$('form').enterNav('textarea, select');
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <select>
    <option>Looks</option>
    <option>like</option>
    <option>it</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>works</option>
    <option>OK</option>
    <option>?</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: one more question, if i use textarea or dropdown. it's not working. Any solution?

Comment: Hi @DarpanPatel I'll probably need more info like the ancestor that all targets have in common. I've added another demo with textarea and selects in a form and it works.

Comment: That's what i needed, Thankss

Comment: No problem, glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery here, just plain old js does the trick. As per your request in the comments above, focus is set on the first entry in the second table. Note that no additional class or id specifications are necessary for this.

```js
// Target last table in the group
tables = document.getElementsByClassName('gridexample');
targetTable = tables[tables.length - 1];

// Target first row of the last table
tableRows = targetTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
targetRow = tableRows[0];

// Target first entry of the first row of the last table
rowEntries = targetRow.getElementsByTagName('td');
targetEntry = rowEntries[0];

// Get the input field and set focus
targetEntry.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
```

```html
<table class="gridexample">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="gridexample">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```